# How to merge all the partitions to normal

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, high-sierra

So I was trying to use bootcamp to use windows 10 because I need to use Visual Basic for my university and it failed and I’m not so sure how ended up with all these volumes. I have copied all important files to another USB so is there an easy way to clean up all the non-needed volumes so that my Macintosh gets all the space like before I started down this path?

[image][image]

UPDATE: This is after what I got after I followed **klanomath** instructions [image]

Comment: Is there any way to restore the 7.9GB and 55.6GB back to the 187GB HD

Comment: Can you redo the screen shot or upload text showing diskutil apfs list - you have no core storage and you do have APFS. Also, please indicate if you have a backup or need to make one before more damage or loss happens.

Comment: As to the “way to restore” you can always copy data back or use disk utility to restore - be careful a restore wipes everything so it’s not a merge - it’s a true restore which replaces existing data with other data.

Comment: I moved my important documents to a usb drive and don't care if I need to restore to factory settings

Comment: You would have to tell me what cmd to write to show what as I'm a total beginner when it comes to this. And thanks for helping

Comment: Looks good. I’ll edit that you don’t need a backup into the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the default partition layout you have to remove Apple_Boot, the empty container disk2, the almost empty container disk3, erase disk0s3-disk0s4 to free space and finally resize your main container.

Boot to you main system.

Open Terminal and enter:

```
diskutil list
diskutil ap list
```

to get the details.

Check your disk:

```
diskutil verifyDisk disk0
diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2
```

Remove all partitions and container except the main container:

```
diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" Nil disk0s5
diskutil ap deleteContainer disk2
diskutil ap deleteContainer disk3
disktutil list #to get the new dev identifiers of the converted partitions
diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" Nil disk0sY # Y probably one of [3-7]
diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" Nil disk0sX # X probably one of [3-7]
```

Resize your main container:

```
diskutil ap resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Finally `diskutil list` should look more or less like this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB  disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.7 GB  disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            140 GB     disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.3 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: This did solve part of the problem and now my hard disk has a space of 194.87GB but still not that of 250GB

Comment: @AzeemShah Please add a follow-up screenshot of `diskutil list`

Comment: I've updated...

Comment: @AzeemShah You also have to erase disk0s7: `diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" Nil disk0s7` then again `diskutil ap resizeContainer disk0s2 0`

Answer (score 0):

this Link help you to merge ,combine ,delete in your partition

https://www.howtogeek.com/212836/how-to-use-your-macs-disk-utility-to-partition-wipe-repair-restore-and-copy-drives/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant. Also, as the page you link to seems to mainly explain the available options, can you add some details on how to use these tools to solve the specific problem described in the question?